# Rsync link destination folder

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync to back up a folder on a local machine to a remote machine.

The link destination folder is on the remote machine as is the target. When using the command line it works fine - using `link-dest=../../link` - that being the location relative to the target directory. When I try to put this into a script on the local machine it failed to exec `--link-dest=../../link`. In the script I have a variable `LNK="../../link/"` and `TRG="remote@user:home/user/target`. I am pretty new to scripting but this has stumped for a few days now.

I did try the full path on the LNK variable `remote@user:home/user/link` - same result

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why wont the script see the link-dest folder on the remote machine?